# jQGrid Frozen column doesn't work when it's placed within a jQuery Tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, tabs, frozen-columns

I have 2 sections, separated by a jQuery TAB. In my first tab I have a jqGrid with frozen columns and so far it works. However, in my second tab i have another jQgrid with frozen columns that doesn't work.

When I remove the code that converts `<div>` into tabs, both tables are displayed within the same page and are working properly with their respective frozen columns.

I think the problem is within the tab itself, but I just can't find a way to solve this.

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">

  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery( \"#tabs\" ).tabs({});
tableToGrid('#super_summ', {
                    caption: \"Performance Summary By Supervisor\",    
                    shrinkToFit: false,
                    width: '850',
                    height: '180',
                    hidegrid: false,
                    rowNum: 150,
                    sorttable:false,
                    colNames :['Sor','Staime','A T',
                                'NR','C And','Callsd',
                                'T Planned','Tickets Cld','A','S','T',
                                'TA2','Total','TO KP','KP'],
                    colModel: [
                        {name: 'Su', width: '120px',align:'center',frozen:true},
                        {name: 'St', width: '120px', align:'center'},
                        {name: 'AvT', width: '120px',align:'center'},
                        {name: 'N', width: '120px',align:'center'},
                        {name: 'Ca', width: '120px',align:'center'},
                        {name: 'Caled', width: '120px',align:'center'},
                        {name: 'Td', width: '120px',align:'center'},
                        {name: 'Ti', width: '120px',align:'center'},
                        {name: 'C', width: '90px',align:'center'},
                        {name: 'S', width: '90px',align:'center'},
                        {name: 'T1', width: '90px',align:'center'},
                        {name: 'T2', width: '90px',align:'center'},
                        {name: 'Tot', width: '90px',align:'center'},
                        {name: 'TOK', width: '90px',align:'center'},
                        {name: 'KP', width: '90px',align:'center'}
                        ]
                });
                jQuery(\"#super_summ\").jqGrid('setFrozenColumns').jqGrid('sortGrid','Supervisor');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you loading the jqGrid first and then the tabs? You should make the call to the grid function before you make the call to the tab function. The grid should render completely, then the tabs.

Comment: I created the tabs first and then the jqGrids

Comment: I don't think i can due to company's policy, sorry.

Comment: Can you type in an example of what you've done? It is hard to help without seeing the code.

Comment: I've edited my question and added part of my code. The code for the grid that i posted is the one that's giving me trouble.

Comment: you're calling the tabs function before the grid function. Try reversing that so the grid is rendered first, then the tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the order in which things are  drawn, first the grids, then the tabs next.